# Magento 2 soap API 404

Tags: magento2, soap, soap-api-v2, wsdl, webapi

I am trying to load the url: http://magento2.dev/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 in the browser but gives me 404.

Additionally I using SoapUI Software and gives me error too.

> Error loading [http://magento2.dev/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 9): '!

Does anyone here have used/use Magento 2 API and possible could give some advice to help me find what I am doing wrong or not doing right, I appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's the Magento 1 SOAP WSDL call. Magento 2 has a different WSDL for each resource you access (though you can group a few together if needed) and generally will need the Authorization Bearer token set when requesting the WSDLs and making the calls.

The sort of call you need to get a WSDL (curl example) will be:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 2id85tedylw0gsezo2gum984z2zj0zw6" "https://your.site/soap/default?wsdl=1&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1" > orderwsdl
```